# Integer to String error in my program

Tags: python, string, int

I am having a problem with a program I am currently working on. It is a GTIN-8 Code generator. When I try to start the program, I get the error:

```
Type Error: Can't convert 'int' to str implicitly.
```

My code is as follows:

```
sevenNum = ""
gtinNum = ""
checkDigit = ""
total = ""

a = ""
b = ""
c = ""
d = ""
e = ""
f = ""
g = ""

def GTINCalc():
    a = int(sevenNum[0])*3
    b = int(sevenNum[1])*1
    c = int(sevenNum[0])*3
    d = int(sevenNum[1])*1
    e = int(sevenNum[0])*3
    f = int(sevenNum[1])*1
    g = int(sevenNum[0])*3

    total = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g)

    checkDigit = (total + 9) // 10 * 10 - total

    print("GTIN-8 Code:" + a+b+c+d+e+f+g+checkDigit)


def sevenNumAsk():
    sevenNum = input("Enter a 7 digit number to be converted into a GTIN-8 Number")
if sevenNum.isdigit() == True and len(sevenNum) == 7:
    print("Valid Number - Calculating GTIN-8...")
    GTINCalc()
else:
    print("The number is not valid - please re-enter ")
    sevenNumAsk()

sevenNumAsk()
```

I am having problems with this part:

```
total = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g)

checkDigit = (total + 9) // 10 * 10 - total
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot concatenate `string` and `int`s together:

```
print("GTIN-8 Code:" + a+b+c+d+e+f+g+checkDigit)
```

It is more correct to use string formatting anyway, for example:

```
print("GTIN-8 Code: {0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}".format(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, checkDigit))
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @djjordand6 The above line will fix one of the errors but you also have other problems in your code. See AKS's answer as well.

Comment: Also, for other users, just remove the {8} at the end as it gives Range problems. {0} - {7} should be fine for 8 characters.

Comment: @djjordand6 Thanks, fixed it now...

Comment: Yeah have just found some more, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`a`, `b`....`g` are defined as string:

```
a = ""
b = ""
c = ""
d = ""
e = ""
f = ""
g = ""
```

and, when you sum them up `total = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g)`, `total` is a string as well.

I would think your indentation is off in the code. If it is just a copy/paste error while posting the question only, then You can refer to @Selcuk's answer.

Comment: Those variables are not used within the function. The OP is redefining them as ints, as in `a = int(sevenNum[0])*3`

Comment: @Selcuk But the statement `total = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g)` itself is executed outside the function even before the function is called, isn't it? So the OP is redefining them but never actually using them.

Comment: Well, I assumed that it is a copy/paste error; but if not, you are right...

Comment: @AKS Despite changing the values of 'a', 'b'... to an integer, it still does not work.

Comment: @djjordand6: Is this the actual code you have posted? Because I see some problems with indentation. Please post the actual code with proper indentation and then we will be in a better position to help you.

Comment: @AKS Edited, three lines weren't properly indented

Comment: @AKS it seems as if I am having an index issue now.

Comment: @AKS Do you have any fix to the index issue i am having? I don't know where to start with it since im fairly new to Python